# How good is a 6 minute mile for a 12 year old boy?

Tags: running

How presentable is a 6 minute - 6:30 mile for a 12 year old boy? What ranking or percentile does that put him under?

Answer (score 2):

Using the table at [Running Level.com](https://runninglevel.com/running-times/1-mile-times) which describes mile times for various ages, and male/female categories, a 6:00 to 6:30 mile time run by a boy is "advanced" and is in approximately the top 20% for the age group (approximately the 80th percentile).

Because the labelling is somewhat arbitrary and the ages are only multiples of five, it is possible that they may be in a higher or slightly lower percentile. It is likely that such a runner can do well at local or regional levels, but may struggle at higher competition ("state" or national level).

| Age | Intermediate | Advanced | Elite |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 7:59 | 6:58 | 6:12 |
| 15 | 6:54 | 6:02 | 5:22 |